# Dropdownlists with many conditions - select from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, algorithm

I want to solve problem. I trying to do algorithm, where I can building a queries. For example If I have 1 or 2 condition I can construct my algorithm on programming switches with string format. (pic. 1)

[image: pic. 1]

But if I want more than 2 conditions, I'll be have a lot variants.(pic. 2) 
[image: pic. 2]

I want just SELECT with different conditions from database. 
Maybe someone know what way I should to use to construct a lot different conditions?

Comment: are u fetching from a single or multiple tables?

Comment: the problem is how are the conditions connected, by ANDs or ORs?  or do you want to support a combination of connectors?  If so, you'd have to support parentheses as well, or have a way for the user to specify the condition's precedence

Comment: I fetching from a multiple tables.

Comment: Betch, it can be search by all or any conditions ('OR' or 'AND')

Comment: is the idea that they're specifying search/filter criteria for one denormalized set?

Comment: if you want to offer them all the flexibility of SQL searches, you'll need to give them a text box to write their own WHERE clause, but then you also need to give them details about the model so they know which field names to use.

Comment: Remember to use `SqlParameters` instead of concatenating the sql string to prevent sql-injection.

Comment: if you're using code now and you want an alternative, can you post the code?

Comment: Tim Schmelter, I using SqlParameters. I want write unique algorithm for 1,2,3 or 5 conditions. Maybe I should make some specific object, and this object will add some conditions to List, and after that - running, I don't know(

Comment: Beth, I added all conditions to List, after that parsed all values, and have a big switch with cases, and in all case I added part of SQL-code. Before switch I have template of SQL. And inside someone case I do string.Format() with conditions. But if I'll to the same with 3 or 4 conditions - I'll be have maybe ~500 variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they're always querying/filtering the same denormalized set, you can write a WHERE clause builder, but you'll need to treat each field/operator/value and clause independently.

Each value in your field combo box should correspond to one `table.field` name in the set, each value in your operator combo box corresponds to SQL operators to add to the clause, and you'll have problems with your values they enter because you'll need to distinguish between numbers and strings, formatted without or with single quotes.  Also, there's date formats to consider.

You may also get people making combinations of fields and operators that don't make sense.  'After' makes sense for dates, but not email addresses.  Consider limiting your choices in the operator combo by the data type of the field selection.